# In Angular2, what is ChangeDetectionStrategy scope of influence?

Tags: angular

Once defined in a certain component does the ChangeDetectionStrategy option is determinant in all its descendent components in the application component tree? That is, if it is defined ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in a certain component, then will all its descendent components have this behaviour?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Angular 2 change detection works top to bottom with changes trickling down from parent to child.  The strategy you set on any given component will be applied, and importantly can not be overridden on any child components.

This has tripped me up a few times and is a real pain to debug.  You have to think carefully about your applications structure and ensure change detection is applied to the correct components.

This is a useful article (http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) which helps explain how it works much better than I can.